# How can I get my money back after it disappeared from stock market?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

After doing the first assassination mission for Lester I put $43.5 million in the stock market and it won't show up. How can I get it back?

Comment: Are you sure you're on the right character?

Comment: Yes it's in recent purchases for Michael but not in my portfolio